# Why should the layout_width be set to ZERO?

Tags: android, fragment

when I learn fragment on

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

I saw the following code in layout-land/fragment_layout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment class="com.example.android.apis.app.FragmentLayout$TitlesFragment"
            android:id="@+id/titles" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/details" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?android:attr/detailsElementBackground" />

</LinearLayout>
```

why the layout_width's of fragment and framelayout are both set to zero ??
I tried the same xml on portrait orientation, setting `android:orientation="vertical"`, and a blank screen was shown. So what's the secret in there? I mean what's the difference between vertical and horizontal? what's the special feature of that `FrameLayout` ?

Comment: the secret is ***android:layout_weight="1"*** [learn more](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3996104/488434)

Comment: Its a fix to a bug on some versions of android where layout weight isn't respected correctly if the width is wrap_content or fill_parent.  For some reason that makes it correctly weigh the two equally across full-screen.

Comment: @AhmadAl-Kayyali Thank you very much :) I change the xml as `android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0px"` when vertical, It worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the thing you are looking for is the weight property which is dividing your `LinearLayout` into two equally portions.

The secret is **android:layout_weight="1"** [learn more](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight)

Answer (score 0):

If your LinearLayout is vertical orientation than each item with layout_weight attribute have to set layout_height to 0

In case of horizontal LinearLayout you have to set layout_width to 0 if it has layout_weight